# Seeing register contents in ASCII in gdb

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb

[image]

Suppose, I am at this position now, and I want to see the content of cl, ch, cx, ecx, etc in ascii format.

What to do?

The following is the subroutine displayed in the `layout asm` command.

```
RemCharCodeFromAToB:
    ; standard entry sequence
    push    ebp             ; save the previous value of ebp for the benefi$
    mov     ebp, esp        ; copy esp -> ebp so that ebp can be used as a $   

    ; accessing arguments  
                            ; [ebp + 0] = old ebp stack frame
                            ; [ebp + 4] = return address
    mov     edx, [ebp + 8]  ; string address

    while_loop_rcc:
        mov cl, [edx]       ; obtain the address of the 1st character of the string
        cmp cl, 0           ; check the null value  

        je  while_loop_exit_rcc     ; exit if the null-character is reached

        mov al, cl ; save cl
        mov cl, [ebp + 16]      ; end-char
        push cx                 ; push end-char
        mov cl, [ebp + 12]      ; start-char
        push cx                 ; push start-char
        push ax;                ; push ch
        call IsBetweenAandB
        add esp, 12

        cmp eax, 0          ; if(ch is not between 'a' and 'e')

        je inner_loop_exit_rcc

        mov eax, edx    ; copy the current address

        inner_loop_rcc:
            mov cl, [eax+1]
            cmp cl, 0
            je  inner_loop_exit_rcc

            mov [eax], cl

            inc eax
            jmp inner_loop_rcc
        inner_loop_exit_rcc:

        inc edx             ; increment the address
        jmp while_loop_rcc  ; start the loop again
    while_loop_exit_rcc:

    ; standard exit sequence
    mov     esp, ebp        ; restore esp with ebp
    pop     ebp             ; remove ebp from stack
    ret                     ; return the value of temporary variable
```

- Full asm code [is here](https://pastebin.com/dSsNy1B3).
- C++ code [is here](https://pastebin.com/S6SE2mFW).
- Makefile [is here](https://pastebin.com/sS0u7bpL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will define an `asciiprint` macro, which will print its argument register's value as a  sequence of characters, from least significant byte to most.

```
(gdb) define asciiprint
 set $len = sizeof($arg0)
 set $val = (unsigned long long)($arg0)
 while $len-- > 0
   set $char = $val & 0xff
   if $char >= 0x20 && $char <= 0x7e
     printf "%c", $char
   else
     printf "\\x%02x", $char
   end
   set $val >>= 8
 end
 printf "\n"
end
```

```
(gdb) set $rcx=0x6b63616a70616c66
(gdb) asciiprint $rcx
flapjack
(gdb) asciiprint $ecx
flap
(gdb) asciiprint $cx
fl
(gdb) asciiprint $cl
f
(gdb) asciiprint $ch
l
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you type the following command:

```
print (char)$ch
```

... you will see the value of the register `ch` as ASCII character:

```
$3 = 70 'F'
```

However, this will only work for byte registers. If you print a 16- or 32-bit register this way, only the low byte will be printed.

You may use a right shift to print 8 bits in some register as ASCII character. The following example will print bits 27...20 of `ecx` as ASCII character:

```
print (char)(((long)$ecx)>>20)
```

Comment: That is not what I wanted.

Comment: @user366312 Can you give an example for an output that you expect for a certain register value?

Comment: Say, if ecx contains 99 or 0x63, I need to see the character 'c'.

Comment: If the register value is in the range 0x00...0xFF, you might replace "`ch`" by "`ecx`" in my first example: "`print (char)$ecx`" Actually, this will print `cl` then; however, this would also work for 32-bit registers that cannot be accessed byte-wise. I doubt that there is any possibility to do this if the value is >= 0x100 because it is not clear what the debugger should display in this case.